# Python IDLE Multi-line Prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I'm using the IDLE command prompt with Python 3.3 and when I enter a multi-line command, I see a blank line rather than the multi-line prompt that has three dots.  I know that this is a little thing, but does anyone know how to enable the multi-line prompt?

Comment: This is because it is a multi-line command... Multi-lines don't use the `>>>`... When you press enter twice and exit out of the multi-line, the `>>>` will reappear.

Comment: Use the shell(terminal) instead of IDLE if you want the `...`.

Comment: This is an intentional design decision (you may notice that IDLE ignores whatever `sys.ps1` and `ps2` you set inside a shell window—IIRC, some versions actually `del` them), and IDLE isn't all that configurable. However, it _is_ pretty readable pure Python code, so there's nothing stopping you from copying the code out of the stdlib (or [online](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/idlelib/)) and modifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, IDLE will not display the three dots that you are looking for; however, if you must have them, you could always run python from the terminal by typing 'python' into the terminal and pressing ENTER. To exit python from the terminal you could type either 'exit()' or 'quit()' followed by ENTER.

Answer (score 2):

Download Dreampie. It splits the prompt into two parts, a working area, and a results area.

It is quite similar to IDLE besides that.

http://www.dreampie.org/download.html